# Leaflet "maxBounds" woes on a non-geo map

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leaflet to display a *non-geo* map: that is to say, a "paper map" of definite size which has been cut into tiles using appropriate software.  For the moment, I'm generating all of the zoom-levels from zero ("the entire map in one square ...") to whatever-zoom fits the entire map at actual size.

And what I find *(Leaflet 0.7.3)* is that, if the zoom-level is such that the size of the map is less than the size of the container in which the map is situated, and **if** I use `maxBounds` keyed to the size of the map, then a great many things seem to go wrong:

(1) If the zoom-level is such that "not-all four sides of the map are surrounded by empty space," then the map is anchored to the lower right-hand corner and cannot be moved from it:  it "pans back to where it was."

(2) If the zoom-level *is* such that "all four sides are surrounded by white space," then the map-display re-centers itself in the center of the window (if you try to move it elsewhere), *but* the markers spill outside the boundaries of the area in which the map sits.

If I turn off `maxbounds`, then the markers still lie outside the boundaries of zoomed-out maps *(#2 above)*, and the "stuck in the lower right corner" *(#1 ...)* behavior no longer occurs, but of course you can now scroll away from the map such that you'll never be able to find it again.

*Ex minimis,* I need to find a solution to "problem #1."  I need to make sure that the map, at whatever zoom-level, cannot "completely escape the bounds of the window."  I'm resigned to the fact that I might have to write my own code to do this, but I have no idea *how.*  (So, I'm anxiously hoping that someone *else* has already banged his/her head against this??)

I can probably circumvent "problem #2" by avoiding too-small zoom levels.  I was *lead to believe* that this could be done just by "not specifying `min`Zoom at all," but this does not seem to be the case.

Help??

Answer (score 1):

Most recently, I have found that "the only situation where this *really* doesn't seem to work is:  zoom-level zero, where there is only one tile."  If you limit your minimum-zoom to "1," or to whatever minimum-zoom that causes the display to overlap the boundaries of your `<div>` "however slightly," many Leaflet problems appear to be bypassed.